# report server: publish some pages from report (not all)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, power-bi-report-server

Would you help me, please, to solve the problem:

I have a report on report server (SSRS), which contains two pages (A and B).

```
client 1 wants page A from report
client 2 wants page B
client 3 wants pages A & B
```

The method I suggest is:

```
-create 3 reports
-in all reports create links to general datasets.
```

But it requires updating plots and graphs twice in case of changes.
Is there some method to create one report and restrict number of pages during publishing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this..

### Option 1: Subreports

You can do this easily with sub reports.

Create "Page A" and "Page B" as separate reports, this will satisfy the requirements for Clients 1 and 2

Next, create a new report (e.g. "Full Report") and insert two subreports, point the first subreport to your "Page A" report and the second subreport to your "Page B" report. When you run "Full Report" it will simply run both sub reports.

When you need to make a change, you only need to do this to either the "Page A"  or "Page B" report.

### Option 2: Paramterise the report

The other way do to this would be to add a parameter to your report that you use to control the visibility of all the objects on each page.

If the parameter was called `pClient` for example then the `hidden` property on all objects on page A would be something like

```
=Parameters!pClient.Value = 2
```

This would hide everything on Page A when the client is set to `2`

The problem with this method is that you might end up with blank areas in your report where things are hidden and it might be more complex to manage if you have more complex requirements than those in your example.

**Finally,** If any of this does not make sense, let me know which option you are interested in and I will explain in more detail.

Comment: Alan, thank you very much. I used Option1.